# Deleting images from Cloudinary using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I am trying to delete images from cloudinary using node, I've read the documentation and the code is as follows

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id, options, callback);
```

I've tried this method but I keep getting an error that uploader is not defined, so I thought it was using the name you used to initialize multer and I did it like so

```
const parser = multer({ storage: storage });
```

However, it's still showing me that 'parser is not defined', so I am confused on how to continue this and I was hoping someone might help me figure this out as I saw a similar question answered a while back and the answer is still the same as the way I said I did, so I don't know if maybe the documentation changed.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({ 
    cloud_name: "########", 
    api_key: "########", 
    api_secret: "########" 
}); 
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy('sample', function(error,result) {
  console.log(result, error) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

cloudinary.config({ 
 cloud_name: `${process.env.CLOUD_NAME}`, 
  api_key: `${process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY}`, 
  api_secret: `${process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET}`, 
});

const response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(localFilePath, {
    resource_type: "auto", 
});
return response;
```